# Why does adding a non-VLANed interface to a bridge break the VLANed interfaces?

Tags: linux, bridge, vlan

I'm working with VLANs on briges and have found that if I add a non-VLAN interface to any bridge, it breaks all the VLAN interfaces - packets leave just fine, but the return packets (which are appropriately VLAN tagged) are getting dropped somewhere. The minute I drop the non-VLAN interface from the bridge, the VLAN interfaces start working again.

What is the reason for this? Is it a bug?

To clear up any possible questions:

```
#setup bridges and vlans
vconfig add eth0 2
vconfig add eth0 3
brctl addbr br2
brctl addbr br3
brctl addif br2 eth2.2
brctl addif br3 eth2.3
ip link set dev br2 up
ip link set dev br3 up

#wait for forwarding state and test
arping -I br2 10.10.10.1
#this works - I get replies
arping -I br3 192.168.1.1
#this works - I get replies

brctl addbr br0
brctl addif eth0

arping -I br2 10.10.10.1
#broken - no replies. Wireshark shows reply packets coming in exactly as before.
arping -I br3 192.168.1.1
#also broken

ip link set br0 up
#wait for forwarding mode, then...
arping -I br3 192.168.1.1
#still broken

brctl delif br0 eth0
arping -I br3 192.168.1.1
#working again!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular example, `br0` is consuming the packets from `eth0` and the VLAN code is not getting them. That's probably the right behaviour.

If you are adding a trunk port to a bridge, you should run the VLANs off the bridge:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ip link set br0 up

vconfig add br0 2
brctl addbr br2
brctl addif br2 br0.2
ip link set br2 up

vconfig add br0 3
brctl addbr br3
brctl addif br3 br0.3
ip link set br3 up
```

I don't have my bridge & vlan setup handy, so I can't test this, but it makes logical sense to me. It removes the conflict between whether VLAN or bridge consumes packets from eth0 and makes the layering clear.